# issue with pushing to navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I have the following code:

```
- (void)setupBook
{
    if (self.bookNavigationController) {
        BookViewController *bookVC = [[BookViewController alloc] initWithTemplate:x];
        self.myBookVC = bookVC;
        [bookVC release];    
        myBookVC.pageTitle = @"My Book";
        UINavigationController *nController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myBookVC];
        self.bookNavigationController = nController;
        [nController release];
    }
}
```

and then in the other parts of the code I have:

```
[self.someOtherNavigationController pushViewController:self.bookVC];
```

however now when I try to present self.bookNavigationController as a modal view controller, it is as the myBookVC is not there. why is this? It just shows up an empty view with a navigation bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When to first create your view controller you are assigning it to a property, however when assign to as the nav controller's rootViewController you are referencing an ivar.  Use the property instead when assigning the rootViewController.

```
BookViewController *bookVC = [[BookViewController alloc] initWithTemplate:x];
bookVC.pageTitle = @"My Book";
self.myBookVC = bookVC;
[bookVC release];
UINavigationController *nController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.myBookVC];
self.bookNavigationController = nController;
[nController release];
```

Comment: did that and didn't help as well